# HTML select element using dynamic values from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my data:

```
select * from extension;
+---------+-------+
| ext_num | name  |
+---------+-------+
|  574324 | joe   |
|  564334 | sarah |
|  987652 | pete  |
+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm trying to insert

```
selected="selected"
```

dynamically whilst looping through the table.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM extension")) {
 print "<select>\n<option>select a value</option>\n";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
        printf ("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>\n", $row["ext_num"], $row["name"]);
    }
 print '</select>';
}
?>
```

What's the most simple/efficient way to implement the following:

```
<option value="987652" selected="selected">pete</option>
```

(especially: selected="selected")

into my loop using code similar to the above?

Comment: Where do you get the data that specifies that 'pete' should be selected?

Comment: @Pankrates This would come from a form submission or $_POST. Do I need some more data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok supposing you get the to be selected row from `POST` you could put a condition in the `while` loop that checks the specific post variable

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        if ($name==$row["name"])
            echo '<option value="'.$row["ext_num"].'" selected="selected">'.$row["name"].'</option>';
        else
            echo '<option value="'.$row["ext_num"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user this code :

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "cookie", "pass", "test_intranet");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$selItem = 987652 ;
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT CONCAT('<option value=\"',`ext_num `,'\" ',IF(ext_num=$selItem,'selected=\"\"',' '),'>',`name`,'</option>') AS 'row' FROM extension")) {
 print "<select>\n<option>select a value</option>\n";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
       echo $row['row'] ;
    }
 print '</select>';
}
?>
```

for more performance and use selected="" in continual in query.